# execute adb shell input swipe command from apk

Tags: android, shell, apk, adb

I am trying to execute swipe command from my Apk using

> process =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("adb shell input swipe 250 300
>   -800 300");

but nothing happens and no error occurs during runtime.

Do i have to add anything in manifest to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only execute */system/bin/input* as the *root* or *shell* user; this will not work in an app. The command should not start with "adb shell" when running from the app.

To run the command as root:

```
Process su = null; 
try { 
    su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    su.getOutputStream().write("input swipe 250 300 -800 300\n".getBytes());
    su.getOutputStream().write("exit\n".getBytes());
    su.waitFor(); 
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally { 
    if (su != null) { 
        su.destroy(); 
    } 
}
```

You should also check out third party libraries for handling su commands: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/451

Comment: Thanks a lot..works fine was working on it since last two weeks :)

Comment: I don't get an exception but it doesn't do anything for me. Tried it from adb and saw the swipe produced, just can't get it to work from withing the app. How can I check what is going wrong? Do I need the app the be signed as system app?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put INJECT_EVENTS permission in your manifest:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"
```

Comment: I did not know that this existed. Is there a place where I can read up more on this?