# adb shell command from android app

Tags: java, android, shell, adb

When I try to run the following

`process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input touchscreen swipe 100 1000 300 1000 1000"); //Normal swipe`
 it works.

However, when I am using it as following, it is not working.
`String[] inputs = {"adb", "shell", "input touchscreen swipe 500 1000 600 1000 1000"}; 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(inputs);
p.waitFor();`

I've another command which I want to run, and for it to run, I have to use the second approach. Can someone tell me what is the reason or how can I make the second one run?

Comment: What error it is throwing ?

Comment: @nakul it doesn't throw any error. It just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Geno Chen mentioned, the parameters, need to go with double quotes.
`String[] inputs = {"input", "touchscreen", "swipe", "100", "1000", "300", "1000", "1000"};`
`p.waitFor();` must be removed to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(inputs);
```

throws a couple of exceptions, including but not limited to IO, Null Pointer, Index Out of Bound.

Try surrounding that line with a try catch

```
Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ch);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I have specified exact snippet to keep the context clear. The catch blocks are already in place. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You should paste what the error is, if it exists. (For example, in logcat.)

`adb` is the client, which may not exist in your Android device (since Android 5.0+). You are not expected to use it in your Android App command. For your sample, you can directly use `input` command without `adb`.

Also,

`process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("input touchscreen swipe 100 1000 300 1000 1000");`

is equivalent to

`String[] inputs = {"input", "touchscreen", "swipe", "100", "1000", "300", "1000", "1000"};
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(inputs);`.

Note the dropped first two element in `inputs` from your question.

Comment: There is no error. It just doesn't work.... As I mentioned in my question, the first one works smooth and fine. The second one doesn't. After changing to what you've suggested, it seemed to create just one event (may be a down) and then kept a lock, which resulted in an ANR.

Comment: @grad9 As of my test (AIDE 3.2.161123, MIUI 8 7.3.23 on Android 6.0.1), I successfully run these two code in my answer, both with the expected phenomenon. I don't know if there are some errors on my phone (compile cache, or build cache, etc.) or in your code (coding error, etc.).

Comment: I am using AIDE Android Studio 3.1.2, Build #AI-173.4720617 && Huawei CRR-L09, 5.1.1. Maybe you could find that the solution doesn't work on other devices/os versions etc. The example speaks of chained commands and chained args..

Comment: In the related questions, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337921/execute-adb-shell-input-swipe-command-from-apk, this question may possible duplicate.

Comment: thanks for your help. p.waitFor(); had to be removed to get it working.